# Long Running Transactions in JDBC

Tags: java, spring, jdbc, transactions, spring-transactions

I am rewriting a legacy application. It is basically a form with a cancel and save button where save means commit and cancel means rollback!

To accomplish this the App stores a Jdbc-Connection in the session for the user and retrieves it from the session for db-operations.

Here is a sample sequence of statements:

```
-> user login
Connection conn = dataSource.getConnection();
conn.setAutoCommit(false);
-> user interaction
List items = conn.query(...);         //jdbc query
-> user interaction
Item item = conn.callStatement(...)   //call stored procedure inserting data
-> user interaction
conn.rollback(); // cancel all modifications by the user (in this session)
conn.commit();   // commit the rollback (?)
```

I have never seen such usage of transactions and in my opinion it is a misuse of the concept. Since the modifying stored procedures are a black-box for me, I am afraid i have to copy this approach.

Is there a better way to accomplish this? without storing the connection in the web-session? does springs PlatformTransactionManager support this?

Comment: That is truly weird legacy code... (?!)